# Is there a way to compile a LaTeX table into tab delimited text?

Tags: tables, conversion

I am submitting a manuscript to a journal<sup>1</sup> that will only accept Word or .rtf submissions (arrrg!) and they require that tables be tab separated text.

Is there a way to compile LaTeX tables into tab separated text?

I am using `latex2rtf` for the main document but this embeds the tables.  I also tried `detex` but that didn't strip the table formatting (e.g., `&`).  I am running texlive on Linux.

Thank you.

1. The journal is [Freshwater Biology](http://www.wiley.com/bw/submit.asp?ref=0046-5070) FYI

Comment: Maybe you can use a search and replace approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An automatical way doesn't exist. But you can replace the `&` with `\>`. Then you only have to define a preceding line which defines the tabstops like

```
foo \= bar \= baz \= foobar \= foobarbaz\kill
```

or

```
\hspace*{1cm} \= \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{1cm} \= \hspace{3cm}\kill
```

The `tabular` environment has then to be replaced by `tabbing` environment.
Should be possible if you do not have too many tabulars

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you briefly explain what your code is doing or point me to a place where I can read up on it.  I don't really follow what you are suggesting.  Thanks

Comment: it converts your tabular into a tabbing environment with tab stops. Here is an example: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/Tabulars-E/01-02-2.ltx

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a way to batch process a bunch of tables so I wrote a `sed` script to convert the LaTeX formatting.  The basic script is below but it is easy to add lines for special cases (e.g. `s/\\---/-/g` would convert all of the LaTeX `\---` dashes to just `-`)

```
s/&/\t/g                    # replace LaTeX & delimiters with tab
s/%.*/ /g                   # remove LaTeX comments
s/\\.*/ /g                  # remove all remaining LaTeX formatting
```